# Determining the previous version of r that produced an older R data file

Tags: r, version, lme4

So I had run some mixed models on an older version, an unknown version of R. These models had converged, however, I recently updated R to 3.1.1, and now these models don't converge.

I would like potentially revert back to the previous (yet unknown) version of R, and re-run the models to check and make sure that they actually converged on that version.

The specific question I have is:

Is there a way to determine the previous version that produced the results that are saved in a given data file? If so, how?

Alternatively, I do know that the data file was produced on the last version that I had installed, so if I can somehow figure out which version that was that would suffice. I should note that it's unlikely that the last version that I installed corresponds to the last version offered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, but I think the answer is "it will be difficult".  The easiest thing might be to try to install previous versions of `lme4` and see if one works; the `install_version()` function from the `devtools` package will help (although you will need compilers etc. installed), and cross-checking with the [lme4 package archive](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lme4/).  Having *some* idea of the date range you're looking for (one year ago? two years ago?) will help.  If you go too far back in time you will start hitting dependency problems ...